# PHP Object creation Looping

Tags: php, arrays, loops, object

I have a class to manipulate orders. I have created multiple methods for each purpose too. There can be multiple orders to process which is generated from db. Right now, what I am doing is that, loop through each order and create objects with order id as param to constructor.

```
foreach($order_row as $order_rows)
{
       $order_id=$order_rows->order_id ;
       $warehouse =new WarehouseManager($order_id);
       $warehouse->ProcessWarehouse();
}
```

Is it okay to loop like this? Is there any better way to handle this?

Comment: This looks like it'll work fine. Do you foresee any specific problems with it? The "best solution" generally depends more on context and goal than anything else.

Comment: Create array of objects, so that you can even access the all orders after the loop.

Comment: You're overwriting `$warehouse` on each iteration, and it doesn't really look like you would need a new instance of the `WarehouseManager` for every iteration, but that really depends on what the class does ?

Comment: It is important to send the order id through constructor. So this will do good?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to create new object for each order. What if there is a huge number of records returned?, You only need to create one object to process an order one by one.

```
$warehouse = new WarehouseManager();
foreach($order_row as $order_rows)
{
    $order_id=$order_rows->order_id ;
    $warehouse->setOrder($order_id);  // this method should be implemented first
    $warehouse->ProcessWarehouse();
}
```